# How do I maintain crlf in MS Access text field

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I'm importing data scraped from an old web based database and placing the contents into MS Access. The old database has text fields with crlf's and blank lines but when I write this data into Access it all disappears. If I write the same data to a VB message box the crlf's are maintained so I guess something to do with the Access field (I've tried plain and rich text but no difference):

```
rsu!comment = (xmlNode.nodeTypedValue) 'Write content to database
MsgBox (xmlNode.nodeTypedValue) 'Debug msgbox
```

So I went back to basics and simply wrote the following string to the database but still got the same result:

```
teststr = "This is Line 1" & vbcrlf & "This is Line 2"
rsu!comment = teststr
MsgBox = teststr
```

So it seems it could be an access field/text box format issue?

Has anyone got any code that successfully writes crlf's to an MS Access long text field formatted as "Rich Text" and displays correctly in a text box?

Comment: Exactly how are you viewing the inserted Access data when you see no CrLf/blank lines?

Comment: Hi Tim - Using a text field on a form

Comment: Also if I copy the text field contents back into Notepad++ there are spaces instead of crlf

Comment: Sorry I don't have Access to test with.

Comment: Does this put what you want into the rich text memo field? `rsu!comment = "<div>This is Line 1</div><div>This is Line 2</div>"`

Comment: Thanks HansUp - I did something similar using a query on the field:

Comment: Replace([comment],Chr(13) & Chr(10),"<br>")

Answer (score 1):

As stated above this was sorted by running the following query on the 'Comment' field:

```
Replace([comment],Chr(13) & Chr(10),"<br>")
```